# Prevent EC2 IP address redirecting for testing purposes

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, forge

I'm trying to move my website over to AWS. I set up EC2 but I can't find a way to access the dev site I've set up to allow me to test it works before I switch over. The stack is Laravel/Forge and Nginx.

I have assigned an Elastic IP address, and I've enabled HTTP access via port 80. But when I go to the IP address it redirects to the live domain itself.

Same thing when I use the Public IPv4 DNS (`ec2-<IP address>.compute-1.amazonaws.com`).

I've been battling with it for some time. Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This isn't an EC2/AWS issue. The software you have installed on the EC2 instance, either Laravel or Nginx, is responding to the initial request with a redirect. You need to look into how that software is configured, and provide information about that here if you need more help.

Comment: Got it working. The redirect was coming from `/etc/nginx/forge-conf/<mysite.com>/before` file